# How can i add and remove a specific key of a object when using object.keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a leaderboard for a game. The `userInfo` array that i am using contains fetched data from a json table. The array contains `id`, `username`, `bestattempts` and `besttime` along with the data from each category.

This table currently have 4 columns with and all the data from the json table is on table rows. I need to have the table not showing the "id" column, and instead showing a new "Rank" first column with a autoincrement row data [1,2,3,4,5] (Like on a leaderboard).

How can i make that happen with Object.keys working?

```
import React from "react";
import "./LeaderBoard.css";

const Head = ({keys, head}) => {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
    {
      keys.map(key =><th key={key}>{head[key] || key}</th> )
    }
    </tr>
  </thead>

  )
}
const Row = ({row}) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(row)


  return (

  <tr key={row.id}>
    {
      keys.map(key => <td key={key}>{row[key]}</td>)

    }

 </tr> )
}
  const LeaderBoard = ({usersInfo, head}) => {

    const newArray = usersInfo.map(({ id, ...rest }, index) => ({ Rank: index + 1, ...rest }) )

    newArray.sort(function sortByAttempts(a, b) {
    return (a.bestattempts - b.bestattempts) && (a.besttime - b.besttime)
  });


  const keys = Object.keys(newArray[0])



  return (
  <div className="Leaderboard-wrapper">
  <table>
    <Head keys={keys} head={head}/>
    <tbody>
      {
        newArray.map((row) => <Row row={row}/>)
      }
    </tbody>
  </table></div>
)
};

export default LeaderBoard;
```

Comment: Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to separate `id` and `rest` of the properties `const arrayWithoutId = usersInfo.map(({ id, ...rest }) => rest)`

Comment: Thanks! And how can i add a new first column with increment value?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) provides index of the current item as the second parameter in the callback. You can pass `index+1` as a prop: `arrayWithoutId.map((row, index) => <Row Rank={index + 1} ...)`

Comment: Couldn't manage to understand this last message. But added a ```keys.unshift("Rank")```, which added a first column on the table. Now i just need auto increment values. You know how?

Comment: In my previous comment, I suggested adding `Rank` as a prop to `Row`. A better option is to add the `Rank` to the array of objects itself: `const newArray = usersInfo.map(({ id, ...rest }, index) => ({ Rank: index + 1, ...rest }) )` Now you have an array of objects with `Rank` key added and `id` removed. You don't have to add `Rank` manually to `keys`. Each `row` object will have a `Rank` property

Comment: Implemented this, got the ```rank``` column appearing but the data on ```Rank``` column is still ```id``` values.

Comment: If you use `const newArray = usersInfo.map(({ id, ...rest }, index) => ({ Rank: index + 1, ...rest }))` you should get a `Rank` values of consecutive number 1, 2, 3 etc

Comment: Edited to the question code with the updated one, can you check whats wrong?

Comment: Except for the change from `key={row.id}` to `key={row.Rank}`, it should work

Comment: Also you need to add the `sort` logic before adding `Rank`. Otherwise, `Rank` will not be consecutive. You can sort the original array `usersInfo` before creating another array